# Google Cloud A record issue with setting up CWP web panel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, a-record, dns-server

I have a VM deployed at google cloud.

Here is the google cloud setup.
grant-fullen.com.   A   300 35.231.125.190
grant-fullen.com.   NS  21600

ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com.

grant-fullen.com.   SOA 21600
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
ns1.grant-fullen.com.   A   300 35.231.125.190
ns2.grant-fullen.com.   A   300 35.231.125.190
srv1.grant-fullen.com.  A   300 35.231.125.190
www.grant-fullen.com.   CNAME   300 grant-fullen.com.

The domain name resolves correctly. The sub domains resolve correctly as i can tell.

CWP Hosta Name web panel info.
Your Hostname is: srv1.grant-fullen.com and it resolves to IP: 35.231.125.190 [Check Black List]
rDNS/PTR = 190.125.231.35.bc.googleusercontent.com SUCCESS [Check SenderBase]

DNS INFO 
ns1.grant-fullen.com resolves to 35.231.125.190 
ns2.grant-fullen.com resolves to 35.231.125.190

I have created a new site in CWP.

**Problem** New site added in cwp web panel will not load up in a web browser.

nf1j.com dns servers are set to ns1.grant-fullen.com, and ns2.grant-fullen.com

My 2nd level domain register is Name cheap. I contaced them about the ns1.grant-fullen.com and ns2.grant-fullen.com name servers i registered with them.

They have advised me that there is no A record for ns1.grant-fullen.com and ns2.grant-fullen.com at my server provider.
If you look above at the google info i posted i have A records to resolve to an IP.

My **desired** out come is to be able to add a website in the CWP webpanel and use the ns1.grant-fullen.com and ns2.grant-fullen.com to properly load up the new site i added NF1J.com

It looks like I have to add a zone for each 2nd level domain. 
Has anyone used CWP Webpanel ?
I was thinking that the DNS BIND server in the CWP would create the necessary zone (Arecord, CName, etc) . I may not be understanding this process correctly .

Comment: Sorry, we can't help you with CWP or any other web hosting panel. We could only help with your original question because it wasn't about CWP, but about your domain configuration. Since you've changed the question there's not really anything more we can do for you.

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> nf1j.com dns servers are set to ns1.grant-fullen.com, and ns2.grant-fullen.com

Your domain registrar disagrees. GoDaddy says:

> ```
> Name Server: NS1.CENTOS-WEBPANEL.COM
> Name Server: NS2.CENTOS-WEBPANEL.COM
> Name Server: NS3.CENTOS-WEBPANEL.COM
> Name Server: NS4.CENTOS-WEBPANEL.COM
> Name Server: NS5.CENTOS-WEBPANEL.COM
> ```

You need to log in to your GoDaddy account and set the nameservers correctly there.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I changed to a free DNS server while i figure this out.